# Multiple applications against single database architecture

Tags: database, architecture

We are currently creating a new strategy for our inhouse applications. We currently have about 10-15 applications that goes against the same database directly. This is obviously not very good and we want to evaluate our options. As far as I can see we have to choices:

- Duplicate the database and using replication etc for having them in sync
- Create a new application between the database and the 10-15 applications on top.
- Other?

I would very much like to hear your opionions on this. I belive that the second option is the way to go, that also gives us an effective layer to implement caching. But how would you expose this layer for all the applications? Will webservices/rest be the way to go, or are there other, better ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the buzzword answer to this is "Service Orientated Architecture" - which is indeed option 2.

It's a large-scale undertaking, with many exciting dead ends to explore - but basically, instead of thinking about databases and tables, think about the services which those 15 applications need. Some may be shared, some may be specific to one application. Find a way of exposing those services to the applications - but remember that a web service call can be significantly slower than the equivalent direct database call, so don't take "service oriented architecture" to mean that you have to introduce web services everywhere - it's more of a mindset than a product specification.

Replication and synchronisation - in my experience - create very brittle systems, with failure modes that hurt the brain to even think about.

Other - well, you don't actually say what the specific problem is that you're trying to solve. If its performance - the cheapest way of soving performance issues is throwing hardware at the problem. If it's managability - an SOA can help with that - but it often also introduces additional infrastructure into the mix which also needs to be maintained. Make sure you are really clear about what's driving your architecture choices, because there's no single "best" solution - it's all about trade offs.

Answer (score 3):

Analyzing the options you expose:

> *Duplicate the database and using replication etc for having them in sync*

If all the applications need to access the same database, I find duplicating it a bad decission, since you would face synchronization issues (out of date data, etc).

> *Create a new application between the database and the 10-15 applications on top.*

This is indeed a good possibility. If you don't want all these application to depend on the implementation details of the database (for example, a change on one table would affect the code of all of them), you can "hide" the database behind an application that offers "business meaningful" operations to these "client applications".

If you are just facing performance issues, I would suggest to clusterize the database (instead of manual duplication).

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see why 10-15 applications must share a database? Do really all applications have to use all tables?

Start by moving all tables that are unique for each application to a separate database.

When done, it should be quite easy to see if there will be any problems with multiple applications accessing the same database. Normally it doesn't matter unless applications start to cache data (since you'll never know if another application has updated some data that you cache). The most typical approach is to use some kind of messaging for that.

Comment: Well, this is complicated as this is a mix of both old and newer application. This database contains all customer data so there will be a huge job to extract tables that are unique and also most tables are shared by two or more applications.

The messaging approach is absolutly being discussed, but I dont see any "easy" way of implementing this without almost starting all over..

Comment: yes, it's a huge job. What do you think that it will be when you have 5 or 10 more applications?

Comment: I was maintaining 5 applications across 2 databases. Some were rather complex. Once I was familiar with the code I opened MS Visio and had it automatically create a diagram of all the tables in each Database.  I then grouped the tables as best I could by functionality and put color coded blocks around each grouping. I ended not only with a much better understanding of the database, I also found tables that weren't even used. It also made adding new functionality much easier.

Answer (score 1):

An unmentioned option is to have part of logic in stored procedures / triggers etc... Not a good idea, but an idea non the less.

I would say that your second option is the best bet here. If you are on .NET platform, WCF is really easy and powerful way to go.

Comment: We already have big problems with way to much logic in the database which makes this very hard to maintain and also create a lot of hard to understand issues. By adding a layer on top of the database our plan would be to extract some of this logic out to the code.

Comment: Yes, I would strongly advise against any logic in the database, it is procedural, cumbersome, scattered all over, and very very hard to maintain. A layer that exposes the database is practically your only real option here. gl